# pandas class extension not working

Tags: python, pandas, class, extension-methods

I am looking to add a property function in pandas.DataFrame. However, I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sayHello'` when using it.
This is how I am extending the class:

```
import pandas as pd

class pd(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def sayHello(self):
        print('hello')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check instance of `pd` before `class pd`. Here is documentation about how you can [extend pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html).

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the error, so I am guessing that it is due to how you call the sayHello method. Most likely, the the object on which you try to call `sayHello` is not of the class you created.

```
import pandas as pd

class Your_pd_class(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def sayHello(self):
        print('hello')

x = Your_pd_class()
x.sayHello
```

The code snippet above will print 'hello' to the output.

Note two things here:

1. First of all it is bad practice to give a custom class the same name as an imported module as this can cause confusion, hence I changed the name of the class `pd` into `your_pd_class`. I suggest you give it a name you can remember, but not something that is already being used by another module used in the same program.
2. The variable `x` in this example is created as the `Your_pd_class`, if you create the variable `x = pd.DataFrame()`, `x` will be of class dataframe and you will get the error you got. This is probably the case in your piece of code. If you want to use the extended `pd` class, you should create it as the `Your_pd_class` instead of `pd.DataFrame`.

I hope this helps.

#### Edit

A hack to 'extend' the `pd.DataFrame` class would be to refer all `pd.DataFrame` to `Your_pd_class`:

```
import pandas as pd

class Your_pd_class(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def sayHello(self):
        print('hello')

pd.DataFrame = Your_pd_class

x = pd.DataFrame()
x.sayHello
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I should have mentioned that I am not actually looking to create a subclass of pd.DataFrame, I am in fact looking to extend the pd.DataFrame class. That's why I wrote: "This is how I am extending the class"

Comment: In that case I am not entirely sure whether that is possible. However, you could create a workaround for this and let the `pd.DataFrame` reference point to your new class. I.e. `pd.DataFrame = Your_pd_class`, this will ensure that every object that is created as `pd.DataFrame()` actually be `Your_pd_class`.